# Change bold black caption in Facebook's sharing dialog

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is there a parameter to change the bold black text (text "Google" in the example below) in Facebook's sharing dialog? If yes, which one?

[image: example screenshot]

My code:

```js
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  var locationArray = window.location.href.split("/");

  FB.init({
    channelUrl: locationArray[0] + '//' + locationArray[2] +     '/channel.php', //custom channel
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.6'
  });



}
function test(){
  alert("test");
  FB.ui(
    {
      method: 'share',
      name: 'Sharing Test Name',
      caption: 'Sharing Test Caption',
      //picture: 'http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-8BR3-    K0b_lI/VlZ6b3WCM5I/AAAAAAAARmA/ATbes06U8oU/s1600/mustache-smiley.jpg',
      description: "Post to test the sharing funtion available via Facebook's js sdk",
      href: 'https://google.de',
    },
    // callback
    function(response) {
      if (response && !response.error_message) {
        alert('Posting completed.');
      } else {
        alert('Error while posting.');
      }
    }
  );
}
```

```html
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId={{ fbAppId }}&version=v2.5";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div onclick="test()">share</div>
```

Research didn't return anything for me (Facebook's docs, here, Google). Is Facebook not allowing to change that part of the dialog text?

Comment: Change the og:title tag on the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There used to be parameters to control this, I may be mistaken however currently I think the only way to do this is using the Open Graph meta tags.

Comment: The Share dialog accepts the URL to share only, but the Feed dialog still accepts these [additional parameters](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog#params), with the caveat mentioned in the note above there, that you can not overwrite them for certain types of pages (iTunes, Google Play, Facebook profile or page.) It is possible though that this will change at some point in the future as well.